# Load script as soon as possible in Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to code a basic chrome extension and I need to modify an attribute of a webpage's html tag.

But it loads all the webpage's content and then load the content.js script, I need this script to be ejecuted as soon as possible.
What can I do?

Thanks and greetings.

Comment: See the content scripts documentation and use `"run_at": "document_start"`, and MutationObserver.

Comment: Thanks it helped to me :)